# WCF xmlSerializer and Data Contract Attributes

Tags: wcf

I used XSD2Code to generate C# code from given XSD. This tool generated code snipped as below:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class Orders
    {

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
        public int OrderID {get;set;}
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 1)]
        public string Description {get;set;}
     }
```

Coud some one please guide me with following queires, please

1. If I leave the above code as it is, does WCF serializes the above class?
   Currently I'm getting this error on wcf test client: ""this Operation is not
   supported in WCF Test Client".
2. Do I need to add DataContract and DataMember on top of the above generated codes?
3. Which option is beter between DataContract Serializer vs XML Serializer
   Thanks you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It should work, as long as the contract (either the service contract interface or the operation contract method which uses this type) is marked with the `[XmlSerializerFormat]` attribute
2. No - if you decorate the contract with `[XmlSerializerFormat]`, the DataContract/DataMember attributes are ignored (the XML serialization attributes, like the ones in this type, are used instead)
3. The `XmlSerializer` allows you to completely control the XML in which the types are serialized; the `DataContractSerializer` (DCS) doesn't (it's more limited). But the DCS has a better performance, so which one is better really depends on your scenario.

The code below shows a service which uses this type, and it works fine, even with the WcfTestClient.

```
public class StackOverflow_7155154
{
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class Orders
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 1)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Orders GetOrders();
    }
    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public Orders GetOrders()
        {
            return new Orders { Description = "My order", OrderID = 1 };
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        //MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        //XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Orders));
        //Orders o = new Orders { OrderID = 1, Description = "My order" };
        //xs.Serialize(ms, o);
        //Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));

        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true });
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        ChannelFactory<ITest> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITest>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
        ITest proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

        Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetOrders());

        ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
        factory.Close();

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```